# Summing outerHeight of multiple divs

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

I am summing the total `.outerHeight()` of multiple `div`s like this:

```
var h = $('#div1').outerHeight() + $('#div2').outerHeight() + $('#div3').outerHeight() + $('#div4').outerHeight();
```

Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

I was considering something like this (but it doesn't work):

```
$('#div1, #div2, #div3').outerHeight();
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add a class to the `div`s to be able to select them all

```
<div id="div1" class="sumdiv"></div>
<div id="div2" class="sumdiv"></div>
```

Then, use `$.each()` (http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
var sum = 0;
$( ".sumdiv" ).each(function( index ) {
    sum += $(this).outerHeight()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A more functional approach, but it requires the browser to support [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var sum = $('#div1, #div2, #div3').map(function () {
  return $(this).outerHeight();
}).get().reduce(function (sum, value) {
  return sum + value;
}, 0);
```

Or

```
var sum = $('#div1, #div2, #div3').get().reduce(function (sum, element) {
  return sum + $(element).outerHeight();
}, 0);
```

Alternatively, for cross-browser support, you can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
var sum = _.reduce($('#div1, #div2, #div3').get(), function (sum, element) {
  return sum + $(element).outerHeight();
}, 0);
```

But Topener's answer is straightforward, so you might as well go with that.